# how to add delay between messages in kafka js consumer

Tags: node.js, kafka-consumer-api, kafkajs

I am listening from a consumer in kafka js and messages are coming too fast, i want to add delay like, 10 messages per 5 seconds how can I achieve that without losing any messages in queue.

Answer (score 0):

You can [pause consumer](https://kafka.js.org/docs/consuming#pause-amp-resume) on particular topic/partition, wait a bit and resume consuming. If your goal is to deal with message bursts this should be ok, just check if there is a risk of never catching up (i.e. if producer always sends messages faster than you are consuming them).